# How to sort a csv file using python and write the sorted data to the new csv file

Tags: python, csv, sorting

i have a sample csv file with me which contains some random numbers which are not sorted. i want to sort the data from the csv file and i have to write the sorted data into a new csv file. the problem is if i have a data like

```
 3,
65,
20,
21,
19,
34,
8,
0,
22
```

python is sorting based on the first digit only. if i print out the sorted data, i'm getting the below as output.

```
['0'], ['19'], ['20'], ['21'], ['22'], ['3'], ['34'], ['65'], ['8']
```

which is the sorting is performing based on the first digit.

and i want to write the sorted data to a new csv file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like your data are strings, not integers, which is why it's sorting on the first character. Try converting the data to `int`. For instance, if your data is a list called `data`, try sorting it like this: `sorted(map(int,data))`

Comment: it did not help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv


with open('sample.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    i = 0
    new_data = []
        for row in reader:
            if(row[0]!='' and row[0].isdigit()):
                new_data.append(row[0])
                new_data.sort(key=int)
                print(new_data)
with open('newfile.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    writer = csv.writer(newfile)
    writer.writerow(new_data)
```

the above code worked for me. 
thanks for all the contribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to deal with type conversion. Something like this should work:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('in.csv', delimiter=',')
arr.sort()

np.savetxt('out.csv', arr, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have optional whitespace and commas this should work:

```
with open('in.csv') as infile, open(out.csv) as outfile:
    data = infile.readlines() #read data into list line by line
    nums = [''.join([c for c in i if c.isdigit()]) for i in data] #extract only the numbers from lines
    result = sorted(nums, key=int) #sort the numbers by their integer value ascending (default)
    outfile.write(',\n'.join(result)) #write result to file adding `,\n` to end of each number - \n being the newline
```

Comment: can you please explain the code? that would be much appreciated.